# sort elements read into array

Tags: arrays, bash, sorting

While reading `find` results into an array I want them sorted at the same time (mp3's, so by track number, which is the first part of the file name), and thought something like this should do the trick:

```
mp3s=()
while read -r -d $'\0'; do
    mp3s+=("$REPLY")
done < <(sort <(find "$mp3Dir" -type f -name '*.mp3' -print0))
```

but the elements in the array are never sorted correctly (by first part of file name which is mp3 track number: 01_..., 02_..., 03_..., etc.)

Although the following gets the job done, it seems unnecessarily awkward:

```
mp3s=()
while read -r -d $'\0'; do
    mp3s+=("$REPLY")
done < <(find "$mp3Dir" -type f -name '*.mp3' -print0)

mp3s=( $(for f in "${mp3s[@]}" ; do
    echo "$f"
done | sort) )
```

There must be a more streamlined way to get this done, along similar lines to what I was thinking in the first example, no? I have tried reading thru `sort` on both sides of the `find` command, using its numerous options for sorting (-n, -d, etc.) but without any luck (so far).

So, is there a more efficient way to incorporate a `sort` command while the array is initially being populated?

Comment: You'll also want to clear `IFS` if you don't want `read` to modify your data by trimming out trailing whitespace from the filenames.

Comment: Also, `$'\0'` is **exactly** the same as `''`, because bash uses NUL-delimited strings, and is thus unable to store a NUL inside of a string. This works in `-d` for exactly that reason -- the first character of a zero-length NUL-delimited string is, of course, its NUL delimiter. Personally, I consider the `$'\0'` syntax bad practice because it can lead people to believe that bash can store NULs inside strings, which is false, vs just using `IFS= read -r -d ''`..

Comment: ...if you don't _believe_ that it's false, put `$'\0foo'` into a string, and then try to extract the `foo`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default, `sort` assumes newline-separated records.  The call to `find`, however, specifies nul-separated output.  The solution is to add the `-z` flag to `sort`.  This tells `sort` to expect nul-separated input and produce nul-separated output.  Thus, try:

```
mp3s=()
while read -r -d $'\0'; do
    mp3s+=("$REPLY")
done < <(sort -z <(find "$mp3Dir" -type f -name '*.mp3' -print0))
```

#### Example

Suppose that we have these mp3 files:

```
$ find "." -type f -name '*.mp3' -print0
./music1/d b2.mp3./music1/a b1.mp3./music1/a b2.mp3./music1/d b1.mp3./music1/a b3.mp3./music1/d b3.mp3
```

First, try `sort`:

```
$ sort <(find "." -type f -name '*.mp3' -print0)
./music1/d b2.mp3./music1/a b1.mp3./music1/a b2.mp3./music1/d b1.mp3./music1/a b3.mp3./music1/d b3.mp3
```

The files remain unordered.

Now,  try `sort -z`:

```
$ sort -z <(find "." -type f -name '*.mp3' -print0)
./music1/a b1.mp3./music1/a b2.mp3./music1/a b3.mp3./music1/d b1.mp3./music1/d b2.mp3./music1/d b3.mp3
```

The files are now in order.

Comment: Any reason to use process substitution rather than a pipeline for the connection between `find` and `sort`?

Comment: Oh, I see -- the OP did it that way originally.

Answer (score 4):

One way to do do the sorting internally to bash is to use an associative array and put your data in keys, rather than values.

```
declare -A mp3s=()
while IFS= read -r -d ''; do
    mp3s[$REPLY]=1
done < <(find "$mp3Dir" -type f -name '*.mp3' -print0)
```

...then, to iterate over the values:

```
for mp3 in "${!mp3s[@]}"; do
  printf '%q\n' "$mp3"
done
```

As associative arrays are a feature added in bash 4.0, note that this functionality isn't available in 3.2 (which is still in use in some circles, most particularly MacOS).